# $wpdb->insert Database Error Duplicate Entry Error Logging

Tags: errors, wpdb, duplicates, logging

Is there an equivalent to `INSERT IGNORE` in the `wpdb` class?  As I'm fetching and inserting a twitter feed and the field in which I store the tweet ID is keyed `UNIQUE`, I am aware that duplicates are going to occur and do not need Wordpress informing me of them in my PHP error log.  (Note, I would write the query I need and `$wpdb->prepare` it, but for whatever reason, that throws a bunch of other errors [that I'd be happy to share though don't consider them relevant to this question]).

Comment: You could try to update first and then insert if nothing was updated. Or if you want a single SQL command: `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Just out of curiosity, why was your comment upvoted?  Is `INSERT IGNORE` not the done thing?

Comment: "ignoring errors" should be avoided in general, better to take care of it if you can - is my advice ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question directly, there is [`$wpdb->update`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) but nothing that will strictly duplicate `INSERT IGNORE` that I know of. If [`$wpdb->update`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows), does not work I am fairly sure that you will need to write your own query and use `$wpdb->query` and `$wpdb->prepare`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am obviously trying to do things the Wordpress way, but as I said, I'd tried writing my own query and using query and prepare.  THAT SAID, I did NOT do things the Wordpress way when I'd tried that previously in that I was preparing incorrectly!  Writing my own query and correcty passing an array of my $vals quieted Wordpress down.  Thanks again.